# How to set up a really big JVM heap size?

Tags: jvm

According to the JVM 6 documentation, server class machines receive by default an initial heap size as 1/4 RAM or 1GB. Considering our Solaris 64Bit server has 64 GB, the initial heap size will default in as 256MB. Therefore, I need to set manually the heap size using the XMX parameter for 4GB. Though, when I add "-Xmx4096M", Tomcat does not start. Here is the error message:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

What should be my command line parameters to allow my heap to grow up to 4GB?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Some older OS's don't allow processes to have more than 2 Gig.

Comment: Solaris (I just updated the question above)

Comment: are you running a 64-bit jvm?

Comment: java -version gives me: java version "1.6.0_16" / Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01) / Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode). How can I find out if my VM is built for 64 bit?

Comment: your response should be:

java version "X"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build X)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build Y, mixed mode)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for all your input, guys! Though, the output of my `java -version` mentions `mixed mode` which means that it is 64 bits. The real solution is adding `-d64` to force it to run in 64 bits and therefore allocate the 4GBs.

Comment: The fact it's indicated "mixed" mode is not related to the fact you have a 32 bit or 64 bit JVM. It only means that your JVM mixes two modes of execution "compiled" and "interpreted".

Answer (score 5):

My solution based on the comments to the question: you are using 32bit JVM therefore it can't address more than 4GB (non inclusive). Try installing the 64 bit version

Answer (score 4):

According to the output of `java -version`, a 32 bit JVM is installed. If it was a 64bit one, you should get something like `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`.

Try installing a 64 bits JVM and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

Comment: Using code formatting, and a full example command line, would make this answer much better.