# grails run-app out of memory error

Tags: grails, out-of-memory

Hi I am trying to do grails run-app and I get this error during compilation

```
  [groovyc] The system is out of resources.
  [groovyc] Consult the following stack trace for details.
  [groovyc] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

and then a bunch of stack trace
I have java_opts set as:

> set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
>   -Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true"

but still got the error then I unset this and set grails_opts with similar options

> GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx4096M -server"

still getting the error.
What is the setting to be done?
I have 8 GB of total RAM in the system.
Update: Once I set these variable I get an error from grails saying that

> "-XX:MaxPermsize=1024M" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: The Grails auto reloading can exhaust the Java PermGen after a while. Do you get the error while running grails in interactive mode for some time, or are you running `grails run-app` right from the command prompt/terminal and always getting this error?

Comment: I am running it from the command prompt and get the error every time

Comment: So what is using the memory? Have you tried looking with jvisualvm or jmc? Also, what version of grails? Also, what version of Java?

Comment: I am going to look into this, Versions: grails: 1.3.7 , java:7

Comment: basically its not even running with the updated OPTS, throws -XX:MaxPermsize unexpected at this time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398179/how-to-set-up-a-really-big-jvm-heap-size

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the " from your command. IE:

```
set GRAILS_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx4096M -server
```